# filterizr jQuery plugin Sorting with AND operator

Tags: jquery

I am using Filterizr jQuery plugin, right now the sorting works fine but showing with i think with OR operator. Can you please help me how can i manage filtration with AND operator ?
This is the plugin link [Filterizr](http://yiotis.net/filterizr/) 
Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multifiltering with AND logic was added after Filterizr v1.3.0.

I would suggest that you initially download and include in your project the -currently- latest version of [Filterizr (v1.3.4)](https://github.com/giotiskl/Filterizr/archive/1.3.4.zip)

Then when you instantiate your Filterizr you need to set in the initial options the `multifilterLogicalOperator` parameter like this:

```
$('.filtr-container').filterizr({ multifilterLogicalOperator: 'and' });
```

You can also use the `.filterizr('setOptions', { ... })` method to achieve the same effect, after you have instantiated Filterizr, like this:

```
var filterizr = $('.filtr-container').filterizr();
...
filterizr.filterizr('setOptions', { multifilterLogicalOperator: 'and' });
```